# Liquid inside a cup is being Transparent

Tags: node-editor, shaders, transparency, glass

[image: The liquid inside the cup is transparent]
I added a new material for the liquid.Its IOR is set to 1. But the liquid can be seen through...

Comment: Hello :). *Blender Manual* says: Index of refraction (IOR) defines how much the ray changes direction. At 1.0 rays pass straight through like transparent; higher values give more refraction.

Answer (score 2):

IOR is how mutch a volume deforms the light rays going through, 1 being no refraction.

It has nothing to do with whether or not you can see through your volume.
That would be the Transmission value you've set to 1, meaning it 100% transmits light through. If you don't want that, set it to zero.